# Cannot register C++ MFC dlls on other machine

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I've created some DLLs using `C++ MFC`. I've built them in release mode but when I try to register them on other PC with a fresh windows installation `regsvr32` returns error `0x3`.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Use the 'dependency walker' on the other machine to verify that any dependent dlls can be found.

Comment: I would also make sure the file is not blocked.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
3 (0x3)
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Your'e missing a file, or you've computed a path incorrectly.